# Get Azure subscription details of client

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to get details of Azure Subscription of my client. But I do not want to ask for special permission from client. 
What I need is the bare minimum things from my client so that I can login from powershell or rest api and read status of runbook jobs.

If i login from admin account of the subscription than I can easily get those details. But you understand it is not possible to have admin account credential of my client.

Please suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a user in Azure Active Directory and grant that user specific rights using either the Azure Portal or PowerShell\Cli\SDK.
Say read all, or read properties of desired automation account. If you would want like a super minumim, you would need to create a custom role first.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/

Answer (score 0):

If your client placed specific resources within a Resource Group, they may grant you permissions on just that Resource Group (including read-only permissions). This would allow you to have access to needed resources, without having access to other areas of their subscription.

Comment: If you want to go that way, you might as well assign permission to a resource, not a resource group...

Comment: I disagree. If you have, say, a dozen resources within an app, you're now putting the burden on the client to add permissions to every current and future resource. And should permissions need to be revoked, you need to go through the process for every single resource as well. A resource Group serves as the bounding box for all related resources. Futher, the OP can then view the resource group as an object within their own portal, drill down into it, etc.

Comment: Well, i disagree with you disagreeing ;) the op said that he only needs to look at the status of runbook, why would you grant read permission for the whole rg, when op specifically said he prefers bare minimum?

Comment: Hey all !! Thanks for your valuable suggestions, I think for my requirements I'll go with creating a custom role and than assigning that role from Azure Portal -> Subscription -> Access Control (IAM) to a user who is not on client's AD like (user@otherdomain.com). I hope I'm on right track, please correct me if i'm wrong.